# JDBC MySQL only working in test class

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, junit

As said in the title of the question, JDBC seems to work only in test classes, can't explain why.

```
    public static Connection getConnection()
{
    try {
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + database + "?" +
                "user=" + sqlUser + "&password=" + sqlPassword;
        return DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ConnectionLoader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return null;
}
```

The following test passes:

```
assertNotNull("Connection must not be null.", ConnectionLoader.getConnection());
```

But when debugging the project fails with SQLException saying no suitable driver found.

Here's a screenshot of my project in Netbeans, as you can see I included the mysql jar in the libraries.

Am I missing something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load MySQL driver.

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/databasename", "username", "password");
    ...
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That's no longer necessary. The `DriverManager` can load the appropriate class based on the jdbc URL.

Comment: Class.forName actually solved the problem, thank you.